# Can block validation be done using machine Learning Algorithms?

Tags: evm, consensus, sidechain, consensus-by-block, machine-learning

I am looking for a new era of products that leverages the potential of Machine Learning and the blockchain, Thinking of different aspects of Blockchain which can be improved with the help of machine learning.

Can we validate the block's transactions using ML Algos / Come to a consensus using ML?

Exploration appreciated!

Comment: Why would you use ML to validate block's transactions? The algorithms are defined without any uncertainty. Perhaps you can apply ML to higher level protocols to optimize client storage, transactions distribution or optimal mining strategies.

Answer (score 2):

Possible applications that exist at the intersection of blockchain and AI/ML are numerous but I can't imagine how block production or validation would be one of them. As Ismael said first, there is no subjectivity involved. It's a little like thinking about how an AI can help an i7 be a better CPU.

AI as *actors* in a system concerned with ownership is more interesting. Anything a human can do with an Ethereum account is accessible to an AI. And, AI can be a *consumer* of data enshrined in a blockchain, particularly if that data has provenance that helps it rise closer to the level of facts.

Hope it helps.